# Setting selected item background in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

The code below works in the sense that the list items are displayed as expected and if I "click" on one it becomes the "selected item" and in the code behind the matching lvCategory.IsSelected is true. However, the background of the item as displayed doesn't change to indicate it is selected. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:GCDataLayer="clr-namespace:GCDataLayer;assembly=GCDataLayer" mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MultiTest" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CategoryViewSource" 
           d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type GCDataLayer:Category}, 
                CreateList=True}"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Border
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter
            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        </Style>          
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryItemDataTemplate">          
            <TextBox
            Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>          
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox DataContext="{StaticResource CategoryViewSource}" Margin="5"  Header="Category" BorderThickness="2">
            <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"                        Name="lvCategory"         
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryItemDataTemplate}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **override default template** of **`ListViewItem`**. Hence, removing its default triggers and Visual states responsible for showing selected item in different color.

If you don't want any change in appearance, remove default style declaration under resources section i.e.

Remove these resources and it will work fine:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
   <ContentPresenter
       Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
       SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
       </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: If I remove the control template the first item on the list is selected when it loads and it stays that way with no reaction at all to a selection by click.